# Expo AuthSession avoid asking you to sign into another service

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, auth0

How can I avoid this screen and go directly to my authentication provider sign in page (auth0)?

[image]

Comment: this always shows up in development. when your app is deployed this is skipped

Comment: I have the same issue... I try to sign in, it shows this screen  and after clicking it goes back to Expo Go, reloads the app and start from scratch.
So how am I supposed to test  auth authentication in dev? thx!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered same issue and solved it by fixing all incompatible packages shown as warning on my console when start expo.
I used `expo doctor --fix-dependencies` to fix all incompatible packages in my project.
I think the web-browser package I was using wasn't compatible.

Another thing to note is that if you have already authorized a provider, it will automatically redirect back with success and valid access token.